# How to display 'Variation Image' in WooCommerce using REST API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to post Variation Images for product variations using WooCommerce's REST API.

For example:

I have a parent SKU `mAVNISH123456` and multiple child variants `mAVNISH123456_1`, `mAVNISH123456_2`, `mAVNISH123456_3` and `mAVNISH123456_4`.

How do I upload an image for each variant SKU using REST API?

In other words, I am working with a customer who has different color images for each product.

when I send these images - Blue/White/Orange - to the website, only the first image shows. when a visitors selects White or Orange color from drop-down, it does NOT show the corresponding image.

I am using REST API.

Comment: you should edit your answer with indentations and new lines to make it clearer.

Comment: Hello, I adapted your text to make it more readable, using shorter to-the-point phrasing and splitting into paragraphs. If you could add some precise information of what you have tried so far (code), that will help people to find an answer for you. Good luck!